# LogicalDoc build error?

Tags: java, maven, ant

I tried to build LogicalDoc 6.7.1 with JDK 1.7, maven 3.0.3 and Ant 1.7
but it does not work and get these error , please help?

```
D:\maqtary\logicaldoc-6.7.1-src\build\poms>mvn -version
Apache Maven 3.0.3 (r1075438; 2011-02-28 09:31:09-0800)
Maven home: C:\Users\PC\Downloads\apache-maven-3.0.3
Java version: 1.7.0_80, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_80\jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: Cp1256
OS name: "windows 7", version: "6.1", arch: "x86", family: "windows"


D:\maqtary\logicaldoc-6.7.1-src\build\poms>mvn install
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[ERROR] The build could not read 1 project -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR]   The project com.logicaldoc:logicaldoc-parent-pom:62 
(D:\maqtary\logicaldoc-6.7.1-src\build\poms\pom.xml) has 1 error
[ERROR]     Unresolveable build extension: Error resolving version for plugin 
'org.apache.maven.wagon:wagon-ssh' from the repositories [local 
(C:\Users\PC\.m2\repository), central (http://repo1.maven.
org/maven2)]: Plugin not found in any plugin repository -> [Help 2]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e 
switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please 
read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] 
http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/ProjectBuildingException
[ERROR] [Help 2]
```

http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginVersionResolutionException
    D:\maqtary\logicaldoc-6.7.1-src\build\poms>

</code></pre>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error message states, your maven build is failing because something in `D:\maqtary\logicaldoc-6.7.1-src\build\poms\pom.xml` is telling it to use the maven plugin `org.apache.maven.wagon:wagon-ssh`, which doesn't exist in maven central repository, or your local repository, and thus the build fails.

It looks like said plugin can be found [here](https://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.apache.maven.wagon%7Cwagon-ssh%7C2.12%7Cjar)